# How to calculate a Nash equilibrium strategy for toy games quickly?

Tags: game-theory

Given the game of Kuhn poker or Rock-Paper-Scissors, why is it hard to calculate the solution to it? From my very limited understanding, it seems that to solve it you need to employ the counterfactual regret minimization method. The only other way that I've that that this can be solved is through fictitious play, however it does not work for Rock-Paper-Scissors. The solution to the game seems like a fairly simple number that should be easily calculated. Why is it so hard? You need many iterations of the CFR method to converge to a solution. Why can't we easily deduce this?

`Nash Equilibrium for Kuhn poker:

0 = No previous actions

C = Check

B = Bet`




`King-0  Bet

King-C  Bet

King-B  Call

King-CB Call`




`Queen-0  Check

Queen-C  Check

Queen-B  1/3rd Call, 2/3rd Fold

Queen-CB 1/3rd Call, 2/3rd Fold`




`Jack-0  1/3rd Bet, 2/3rd Check

Jack-C  1/3rd Bet, 2/3rd Check

Jack-B  Fold

Jack-CB Fold`

Rock-Paper-Scissors is choose each possibility equally.

`Rock = 1/3

Paper = 1/3

Scissors = 1/3`

Answer (score 3):

There are other approaches - you can solve extensive form games like this by phrasing them as a linear program and then running an LP solver.  Algorithms like CFR scale better with the size of the game, though, which is why LPs aren't the preferred technique for extremely large games.